# subsequent calls of 'rm -rf' not working in 'for' loop

Tags: bash

I want to delete several folder found by `find`. This script works fine only in the first loop in `for`. The `echo` shows that the loop is working fine, but the `rm -rf $f` is not executed in the second and subsequent loops.

```
folder=`find /seriem/docs/it/ -name '*.printed' -printf '%h\n'`

for f in $folder
do
    echo "rm -rf $f"
    rm -rf $f
done
```

In my case the debug output is:

```
rm -rf /seriem/docs/it/afp/PC_58
rm -rf /seriem/docs/it/afp/PC_59
rm -rf /seriem/docs/it/afp/PC_60
```

but only folder PC_58 is deleted.

Sorry if I made something wrong in this post... it's my first on stackoverflow ;)

Working solution:

```
for f in $(find /seriem/docs/it.nrw/ -name '*.printed' -printf '%h\n');
do
    echo "rm -r $f"
    rm -r -v "$f" 

    #do some other stuff. This is why I need a loop
done
```

Hopefully I did it right now ;)
Thanks for all your fast help !!!!

Comment: This script is so dangerous. Don't use backticks \`, they are deprecated. And always, always quote your variables. Never `rm -rf $f`, but always `rm -rf "$f"`. You can do `rm -v`  ans see what is it doing. And why do you use `-f`/force with `rm`?

Comment: instead of backticks, use "modern" command substitution supplied by `$( ... cmds_that_produce_output_here ... )`. ;-) Otherwise a very good first Q. Can't see why it's not working. If you created your script anywhere near a MS Windows machine, then `dos2unix myScript` might help. Good luck.

Comment: @Kamil Cuk - I doubt you can prove your pretension that _backticks \`… are deprecated_. According to the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) it's _the old-style backquote form_, so it has **style**.

Comment: off hand, my first guess is that there is something below PC_59 and PC_60 that you cannot `rm`, due to permissions or something; but for diagnosing, my first question would be : what happens on a subsequent run of the script?  does the 2nd run delete just PC_59?  and the 3rd run delete PC_60?  etc.  or are PC_59 and PC_60 *never* deleted?  the answer to that will point you to your next thing to investigate

Comment: @Armali But backticks have the objective drawback of requiring escaping for nested quotes, where as `$()` creates a new quoting context: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: `-printf '%h'` would print `/seriem/docs/it/` for each match, did you mean `'%H'`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop at all. Use `-exec`.

```
find /seriem/docs/it/ \
     -name '*.printed' \
     -exec sh -c 'rm -rf "$(basename "$1")"' _ {} \;
```

To avoid forking a separate shell for each call to `rm`, put a loop in *that* shell to iterate over the shell's parameters, and use the `-exec ... +` form to pass as many files as possible to each shell.

```
find ... -exec sh -c 'for f; do rm -rf "$(basename "$f")"; done' _ {} +
```

Either approach ensures that the file name is properly quoted before being passed to `rm`.

Comment: There's no need for the shell and `basename` calls. `rm` has no problem with absolute paths. It's simpler to simply `-exec rm -rf {} +`.

Comment: I'd add `-depth` to avoid trying to delete already removed directories.

Comment: `rm -rf -- `: Always end the options with `--` to prevent a variable content starting with a dash `-` to be handled like an option.

Comment: @LéaGris In general, true, but given the `find` command involved, it's not possible for any of the arguments passed to the shell to start with a hyphen (they'll all start with `/seriem/docs/it`).

Answer (score 0):

the $f should be in quotes

```
rm -rf "$f"
```

rather than

```
rm -rf $f
```

is safer.

EDIT: @Kamil Cuk beat me to it

Comment: Quoting will also require removing the `\n` from the call to `find`; it's unnecessary, and the shell strips it during word-splitting on the unquoted parameter expansion.

Comment: `rm -rf -- "$f"`: Always end the options with `--` to prevent a variable content starting with a dash `-` to be handled like an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can have `find` handle the whole delete process in a safe way for you:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env/bash

find /seriem/docs/it/ -regex '/seriem/docs/it/.*\.printed\(/.*\)?' -delete
/seriem/docs/it/
```

#### Find arguments split-out:

- `find`: the command
- `/seriem/docs/it/`: base directory to start the search
- `-regex '/seriem/docs/it/.*\.printed\(/.*\)?'`: the RegEx pattern to apply to the whole path:

  - `/seriem/docs/it/`: path start with this literal
  - `.*`: any number of any character
  - `\.printed`: literal `.printed`
  - `\(/.*\)?`: optional group of `/` followed by any character
- `-delete`: performs deletion of the found/matched files

Comment: Keep in mind that not all versions of `find` will support `-regex` or `-delete`.

Answer (score 0):

If the intent is to remove the entire containing directory when a match is found;

```sh
find /seriem/docs/it/ -name '*.printed' -execdir rm -rf {} \;
```